# Non-Wordpress subdomain redirecting to Wordpress main site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, ssl, https, subdomain

I recently installed a Wildcard SSL on my sever. The domain has Wordpress installed as the main site but the sub-domains are not Wordpress installations.

The issue I'm facing is that every time I'm trying to browse the sub-domains using https protocol [ex.https://sub.domain.com], all I get is the Wordpress main site instead of the sub-domain. The funny thing is that when I type the sub-domain url without the https [ex.http://sub.domain.com] I am able to get the actual sub-domain site as it should be.

I've been looking around for answers but none of the answers/fixes worked so far. Also I took few minutes and worked on my DNS and .htaccess looking for a way to make it work but as it looks, my experience is not enough to make it work.

I would really appreciate any help I can get that could lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Can we see your .htaccess?

Comment: Sure @bobdye . Here you can find it: http://pastebin.com/9KX2hPdM

Haven't played with it too much so probably you will see something wrong, but not sure if it has something to do with my current issue. Thanks a lot for jumping in and trying to help!

Comment: Interesting. Based on you .htaccess, I would have expected the opposite, i.e. for https to work and http not to work.